# Php image file upload, but while post image base 64 string post in webservice give an error 413

Tags: php

I uploaded image through file upload control with 4 mb, it's uploaded.
I want to post data through web-services at that I got image data as base64 string. My code is working on staging very well but while on live server I tried to run script it doesn't work. Image is 768x80 px image of size 188 kb of png format, then it returns following error:

```
 Request Entity Too Large
 The requested resource /web/index.php/webservices/uploadpicture
 does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided in
 the request exceeds the capacity limit.
 Apache Server at www.mysite.com Port 80
```

Hosting server is godaddy. We have no right to modify configuration of apache & php.ini.
I have tried to modify configuration through `.htaccess`.
Created `php.ini` with following settings:

```
max_execution_time=3600,max_input_time = 9999,post_max_size = 64M,upload_max_filesize = 64M
```

Also tried to modify `mod_security.c` module in `.htaccess` with following settings:

```
SecRuleEngine Off, SecRequestBodyAccess Off
My php.ini settings of file size is following.
Directive   Local Value Master Value
max_file_uploads    20  20
max_input_time          60  60
memory_limit            64M 64M
post_max_size           33M 33M
upload_max_filesize 32M 32M
```

I have tried all ways but still I can't resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could pack that base64 image string to something smaller and sent that one instead ?

Also check if the ISP is not limiting the apache config `LimitRequestBody`

Read more here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody

Comment: But I have already upload file with 4 mb higher then it doesn't arise any problem then how limitrequestbody effect in base64 encode string.?